# SSRS Grouping within Totals

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

If I have 2 row groups; year and status, is it possible to show totals for all years grouped by status?

```
Year  Status Value
2014  Open   100
      Closed 200
2015  Open   200
      Closed 300
Total Open   300
      Closed 500
```

Until now I have always achieved this with a "workaround" (creating 2 rows in the total group and using hardcoded formulae `=SUM(IIF(Status="Open",Value,Nothing)` etc but I would like to be able to do this "cleverly".

Comment: Try to specify outer scope for your SUM function (better to point "Year" or "Body" scope, don't remember exact name).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hardcode the status you can embed another tablix into your current one. Just drag and drop a tablix item to the cell where you want to get the total per status group.

Add the total row outside the `Year` and `Status` groups. Drag and drop the tablix to that row in the cell you want to show the total.

[image]

In the Total tablix add Status as group and use `=SUM(Fields!Value.Value)` to produce the total.

It should produce:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.